# How to store a table's values in a list and sort them?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to test if sorting of first names column in a table is working fine or not. This table consists of 3 columns, "First name", "Last name" and "Email".
This is how the first name column is :
[First Name column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAo7p.jpg)
[Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vxv7.jpg)

I can get the all the **"First name"** values in table and see all of them in console. 
My question is how can I store this value in a list and sort them and then compare them with the table values.
Here is the code :

```
int numOfClicks = Int32.Parse(driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='injectview']/div/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/ul/li[8]/a")).Text);
        Console.WriteLine(numOfClicks);
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='injectview']/div/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/ul/li[1]/a")).Click();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
      
        for (int i = 1; i <= numOfClicks; i++)
        {
            IList<IWebElement> records_in_page = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*[@id='injectview']/div/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]"));

            for (int j = 1; j <= records_in_page.Count; j++)
            {
                
                string firstName = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='injectview']/div/div/div/table[1]/tbody[" + (j + 1) + "]/tr/td[1]")).Text;
                Console.WriteLine(firstName);

            }
            driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#injectview > div > div > div > table:nth-child(3) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > ul > li.pagination-next.ng-scope > a")).Click();
        }
```

Rest of the code is just navigating to the page and I just sent the part that gets column's values.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to save your first name in a list and then compare them.
If you have Id/Class name for the first name you can get all the first names with a better approach

```
    List<string> fromTable = new List<string>();  


    for (int j = 1; j <= records_in_page.Count; j++)
    {
    string firstName = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*
    [@id = 'injectview'] / div / div / div / table[1] / tbody[" + (j + 1) + 
    "]/tr/td[1]")).Text
    fromTable.Add(firstName)
    }

    public bool  Comparer(List<string> fromTabel, List<string> fromDb)
    {
        bool equals = false;
        if(fromDb.Count().Equals(fromTabel.Count()))
        {
              foreach (var name in fromDb)
              {
                equals = fromTabel.Any(n => n == name);
                if(equals == false)
                  return equals;
              }

        return equals;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. For this line : `firstNames.Add(firstName)`  I get this error: The name 'firstNames' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: fromTable.Add (firstName)